# referencing a list of variables to do calculations with in r

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to calculate the number of pairwise differences between the strings of 5 variables s1 vs s3, s1 vs s4, s1 vs s5, then s2 vs s3, s2 vs s4, s2 vs s5

```
s1 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAGCAACGGATTCCACCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGATTGTTTGCT',''))
s2 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACAACGAATTCCATCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGACTATTTGCT',''))

s3 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACGATGGGTCCTGCTTACGCGGGTTCAGTAGGTAAATTCTAGGCCGCCTATT',''))
s4 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACAACGGATTCCACCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGACTGTTTGCT',''))
s5 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACGACGGGCCCTGCTTACGCGGGTTCAGTAGGTAAATTCTGGGCCGCTTATT',''))

for(i in 1:2)
{
  for(j in 3:5){
  diff(i.j) <- sum(mapply(function(x,y) sum(x!=y),s(i),s(j)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So keeping your variables and style, I think you want something like this:

```
s1 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAGCAACGGATTCCACCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGATTGTTTGCT',''))
s2 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACAACGAATTCCATCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGACTATTTGCT',''))

s3 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACGATGGGTCCTGCTTACGCGGGTTCAGTAGGTAAATTCTAGGCCGCCTATT',''))
s4 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACAACGGATTCCACCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGACTGTTTGCT',''))
s5 <- unlist(strsplit('TGTAACGACGGGCCCTGCTTACGCGGGTTCAGTAGGTAAATTCTGGGCCGCTTATT',''))

strList <- rbind(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)
diff <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol=3)
for(i in 1:2) {
  for(j in 1:3) {
    diff[i,j] <- sum(strList[i,] != strList[j+2,])
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, that works great, but it seems quite slow, is there another faster way in r to achieve the same thing?

Comment: See the answer below from Matthew Lundberg ... Try using the package stringdist (as he mentions)

Answer (score 0):

s(i) won't work you might try

> get(paste("s",i,sep=""))

and you have the same issue with your diff(i.j). You might call your object diff_i.j or whatever but you can't use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `get` in a loop to retrieve the variables, it's better to put the data into some structure.

Here, you have two logical structures, rather than one, and you're making an outer product of the two sets.  `outer` is useful for outer products, and it requires that the two logical inputs be separate objects.

Here are the two vectors that you're comparing:

```
a <- c('TGTAGCAACGGATTCCACCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGATTGTTTGCT',
       'TGTAACAACGAATTCCATCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGACTATTTGCT')

b <- c('TGTAACGATGGGTCCTGCTTACGCGGGTTCAGTAGGTAAATTCTAGGCCGCCTATT',
       'TGTAACAACGGATTCCACCCATATGGGCTCAGCAGGCAGGTCCTGGACTGTTTGCT',
       'TGTAACGACGGGCCCTGCTTACGCGGGTTCAGTAGGTAAATTCTGGGCCGCTTATT')
```

Here is an expression in `base` which does the string splitting within the function.  The function passed to `outer` must be vectorized, so `mapply` is used to loop over the data:

```
outer(a, b, FUN=function(a, b) 
                mapply(function(x, y)
                       sum(strsplit(x, '')[[1]] != strsplit(y, '')[[1]])
                       , a, b
                )
)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   26    2   24
[2,]   27    3   25
```

What is being computed is the Hamming distance between the pairs of strings.  Package `stringdist` makes this a lot more readable (and probably a whole lot faster):

```
outer(a, b, FUN=stringdist, method='hamming')
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   26    2   24
[2,]   27    3   25
```

And the author of `stringdist` predicted that you would want to do this, so a function is provided:

```
stringdistmatrix(a, b, method="hamming")
```